# Response as HTML instead of XML

Tags: httprequest, xml

How to get response as XML for below URL

[URL](https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/trademark/data/EM500000012319125)

Comment: Nothing to do with Salesforce, remote server requires cookie. f.e. this will work -- https://gist.github.com/kurunve/9adfefcc717f7513f763555c72fe5628

Comment: @kurunve  - the above curl response also HTML only, He is looking for XML response.

Comment: @Devendar my fault, I forget to copy cookie, updated snippet

Comment: @kurunve - If i run that snippet as it is... is it works?

Comment: @Devendar no, not anymore. As far as I got, it want to get fresh cookies. When you run it in anonymous browser window, it does foloowing -- Get empty page with JS file -> that JS file construct cookie and refresh page -> new request with Cookie is performed. Apparently owner of web site does want to use web crawler to get data. My approach would be to host somewhere VM with chromium to save file as is (aka use browser to get file and save it) and call that from salesforce, but that will require a lot of development.